# How do I make this javascript function wait until I've scrolled x pixels down the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Noob here... Thanks for your help!

I want this function (circles with an animated percentage border) to wait until I'm on that part of the page before it starts. I'm just not sure where to put the code.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.percentPie = function(options){

        var settings = $.extend({
            width: 100,
            trackColor: "EEEEEE",
            barColor: "777777",
            barWeight: 30,
            startPercent: 0,
            endPercent: 1,
            fps: 60
        }, options);

        this.css({
            width: settings.width,
            height: settings.width
        });

        var that = this,
            hoverPolice = false,
            canvasWidth = settings.width,
            canvasHeight = canvasWidth,
            id = $('canvas').length,
            canvasElement = $('<canvas id="'+ id +'" width="' + canvasWidth + '" height="' + canvasHeight + '"></canvas>'),
            canvas = canvasElement.get(0).getContext("2d"),
            centerX = canvasWidth/2,
            centerY = canvasHeight/2,
            radius = settings.width/2 - settings.barWeight/2;
            counterClockwise = false,
            fps = 2000 / settings.fps,
            update = .01;
            this.angle = settings.startPercent;

        this.drawArc = function(startAngle, percentFilled, color){
            var drawingArc = true;
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, (Math.PI/180)*(startAngle * 360 - 90), (Math.PI/180)*(percentFilled * 360 - 90), counterClockwise);
            canvas.strokeStyle = color;
            canvas.lineWidth = settings.barWeight;
            canvas.stroke();
            drawingArc = false;
        }

        this.fillChart = function(stop){
            var loop = setInterval(function(){
                hoverPolice = true;
                canvas.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

                that.drawArc(0, 360, settings.trackColor);
                that.angle += update;
                that.drawArc(settings.startPercent, that.angle, settings.barColor);

                if(that.angle > stop){
                    clearInterval(loop);
                    hoverPolice = false;
                }
            }, fps);
        }

        this.mouseover(function(){
            if(hoverPolice == false){
                that.angle = settings.startPercent;
                that.fillChart(settings.endPercent);
            }
        });

        this.fillChart(settings.endPercent);
        this.append(canvasElement);
        return this;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: See if you can borrow from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267794/scroll-page-until-some-height

Comment: You will have to monitor the scroll event for the window object and check scrollTop each time it scrolls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using jquery you can listen for scroll events and check the top of the page.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > partOfThePageYourCirclesFire ) {
        // fire cirlces
    }
});
```